# ZF2 how to realize an always open connection to xmpp server for receiving async messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebase, zend-framework2, xmpp

I'm trying to set up an app server for mobile App push notification with Xmpp. Reading the firebase fcm documentation i've understood that i must establish a persistent xmpp connection with the google server. Through that connection, i'll receive the upstream message from the app clients.

In Zend framework 2.4, which object or pattern I must use to establish an "always on" connection running in background and create an event when a message is received?

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: ZF2 doesn't include (to my knowledge) a XMPP library. You'll have to bring in one of your choosing with composer (i.e. https://github.com/fabiang/xmpp).

Comment: Hi @TimKlever, Thank you for reply. You're right: there isn't any xmpp functionality natively provided by zf2, so I got jaxl library and loaded it in ZF2 by the autoloader config of myModule. I have no problem sending out messages in xmpp (i can open the connection, send the messages and finally close the connection). But to receive messages from FCM Server I must open a connection and keep it open indefinitely. in Java I could use a different thread and notify the main thread when a message is received by the xmpp connection. But in PHP with zf2 ?